# Write data structure not read correct with struct.pack and struct.unpack_from

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this problem in get data in binary file

```
# Write data
f = open(path, 'wb')

start_date = [2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
end_date = [2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for x in range(10):
    f.write(struct.pack('B', 0))
    f.write(struct.pack('I', x))
    f.write(struct.pack('HBBBBBH', *start_date_binary))
    f.write(struct.pack('HBBBBBH', *end_date_binary))

f.close()

# Read data
f = open(path, 'rb')
for x in range(10):
    data_structure = struct.unpack_from("BIHBBBBBHHBBBBBH",
                                        f.read(FILE_INDEX_STRUCTURE))
    print(data_structure)

f.close()
```

Output is

```
(0, 0, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56832, 7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 17292800, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 258, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(7, 257, 0, 0, 0, 222, 7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0)
(0, 0, 56832, 7, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 2014)
(0, 131989504, 258, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 222, 7, 1, 1)
(222, 66055, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 56832, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
(1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 257, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56832)
(0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 222, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 7, 258)
(0, 2304, 56832, 7, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 222, 7, 2, 1, 0, 0)
```

Expected output is that

```
(0, 0, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 1, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 2, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 3, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 4, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 5, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 6, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 7, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 8, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
(0, 9, 2014, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2014, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

**EDIT**

Getting type of structure of item where `'B'` is 1 and `'H'` is 2. Using those types in the same `unpack` function the types are confused and in example where `'BH'` is 3 but return 4.

```
>>> struct.unpack_from("B", '')
...
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 1 bytes
>>> struct.unpack_from("H", '')
...
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 2 bytes
>>> struct.unpack_from("BH", '')
...
struct.error: unpack_from requires a buffer of at least 4 bytes
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running into padding problems. As the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment) say:

> Padding is only automatically added between successive structure members. No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the encoded struct.

See what's happening:

```
>>> struct.pack("B", 0)
'\x00'
>>> struct.pack("I", 1)
'\x01\x00\x00\x00'
>>> struct.pack("BI", 0, 1)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

So you can't pack items separately and then unpack them together, unless you add the padding yourself...

```
>>> struct.pack("B0I", 0)
'\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

or turn off padding altogether:

```
>>> struct.pack("=BI", 0, 1)
'\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: You should also mention the option to avoid padding by giving `=` as first character of the format string.  This would also solve OP's issue.

Comment: @Alfe: Ah, even better.

Comment: @TimPietzcker `struct.pack("=BI", 0, 1)` is perfectly