# unpack_from() des not work with big files

Tags: python-3.x, struct, fixed-width

I try to read data from some fixed width formatted files  (from [here](ftp://ftp-cdc.dwd.de/pub/CDC/grids_germany/daily/regnie/)) using python3.

If I am preselecting just a few lines it works fine, but if I want to go
through the hole file( with about 1000 lines and 611 blocks per line a 4 chars = 2444 chars) python tells me, that `struct.Struct(bytes).unpackFrom(bytes)` needs `a buffer of at least 2444 bytes`, currently I do not know why it has not such big buffer.

Maybe it is helpful, that I am running on a 64 bit Linux with 4 Gig RAM and 20 Gig Swap.

The code snippet is this:

```
#edit
"""rowMask is 611 times 4s, just to prevent you from counting it... """
rowMask="4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s4s"
def readUsableFields(filename,stdPath):
    usableFields=[]
    with open(stdPath+filename,"r") as f:
            count_line=0
            for line in f:
                    count_col=0
                    fields=struct.Struct(bytes(rowMask,"UTF-8")).unpack_from(bytes(line,"UTF-8"))
                    for field in fields:
                            if(field!=-999):
                                    usableFields.append([count_line,count_col])
                            count_col+=1
                    count_line+=1
            return usableFields
```

I also took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943505/unpack-from-requires-a-buffer-of-at-least-4-bytes) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911330/write-data-structure-not-read-correct-with-struct-pack-and-struct-unpack-from) , but they are both not the answer to my problem.

Some help would be nice, If my question is a duplicate(that I did not find) please tell me.

Comment: What is `rowMask`? What is the length of your line? Do all of the lines in your file actually have the same length? Perhaps add a `print(len(line))` statement before the `unpack_from` call for debugging.

Comment: @Blckknght I added the info. the problem is that I do not know why it does not get the 2444 bytes of buffer

Comment: A few comments that may or may not be relevant: You should use `"4s"*611` rather than explicitly writing the long string. You should open the file in binary mode, rather than using (the default) text mode and then re-encoding to UTF-8 in the `unpack_from` call. If neither of those things helps, I'd suspect that your data has a bad line in it somewhere (perhaps a header, or footer?). Perhaps catch the exception and print out the value of `line` at that point?

Comment: Oh somtimes I feel so stupid! it was the footer! thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many fixed width files have a footer (or header) the code

will fail on the footer, as it might not have the right length.

So you will have to check for the correct linelength:

```
rowMask="4s"*611
def readUsableFields(filename,stdPath):
    usableFields=[]

    with open(stdPath+filename,"r") as f:
            count_line=0
            for line in f:
                    count_col=0
                    # len(line) = 611 * 4 +1
                    # as there is a trailing '\0'
                    if(len(line)!=2445):
                            continue
                    fields=struct.Struct(bytes(rowMask,"UTF-8")).unpack_from(bytes(line,"UTF-8"))
                    for field in fields:
                            if(field!=-999):
                                    usableFields.append([count_line,count_col])
                            count_col+=1
                    count_line+=1

            f.close()
    return usableFields
```